# QT 5.7 - google/protobuf file not found - include PATH error

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use google protobuf 2.6 in QT 5.7 (clang 7.0) with QT creator 4.0.3 on OSX without much luck.

The .pro file has

```
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags -- libs protobuf`
```

to include the protobuf library.

In the header file I generated using my proto file contains the line

```
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
```

this produces a compiler error of

```
error: 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found
```

The protobuf package is found by QT with the LIBS += command in the pro file and I have the unfound header files in

```
/Users/<username>/Qt/5.7/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs
```

and

```
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h
```

I installed protobuf using macports.

The header file autocompletes so QT knows where it is so I am not sure how to deal with the file not found error.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
a.

edit:

I think the problem is /usr/local/ not being included is qt path, thus I can find the protobuf package but not any of the header files (even though it autocompletes?). How do I add to PATH in QT with el capitain?

edit 2:
Project file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-07-13T12:13:47
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testexample
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    ../../../protobuf/message.pb.cc

QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../../protobuf/message.pb.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags -- libs protobuf`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Protobuf 2.4 with Qt 5.7 in Windows/Linux/Mac. Download and compile Protobuf 2.4 with the compiler you are using, (Im using MSVC/MinGW on Windows, gcc in Linux, clan on Mac OS). And edit your .pro file. My .pro configuration using this steps:

Load the compiled library for debug/release mode:

```
    #For Windows
    win32 {
        CONFIG(debug, release|debug) {
            win32:LIBS += -llibprotobuf-debug
        } else {
            win32:LIBS += -llibprotobuf
        }
    }
    #For linux
    !win32:LIBS += -lprotobuf
```

Include the path with all protobuf source code:

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "..\\...\\directoty_protobuf\\src"
```

Its working fine for me.